# [next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider />

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I keep getting this error.
Tried for a few hours now and had no luck, I got a feeling that it's the placement of the _app.tsx that's messing the project up.

```
[next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider />
```

[image]

This is how my file tree looks like

[image: tree folder view]

Navbar.tsx

```html
"use client"
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { NavLinks } from '@/constants'
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

const Navbar = () => {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession()
    return (
        <nav className="flex items-center justify-between p-6 lg:px-8" aria-label="Global">
            <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:flex-1 lg:justify-end">
                {status === 'authenticated' ? (
                    <a href="#" onClick={() => signOut()} className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Sign out {session.user?.email}<span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a>
                ) : (
                    <a href="#" onClick={() => signIn('spotify')} className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Log in <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a>
                )}
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
export default Navbar
```

_app.tsx

```html
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
import type { AppProps } from "next/app"
import type { Session } from "next-auth"
import "./globals.css"

export default function App({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps }}: 
  AppProps<{ session: Session }>) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session} refetchInterval={5 * 60}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

Anyone out there who might know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that you are using `app` directory which uses [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#the-app-router) a mechanism that allows you to use [Server components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components) (This was introduced with Next 13).
Inside the `app` directory `_app.tsx` will not be called.
There are two ways to mitigate this issue

1. Use the old `pages` directory and everything should be good
2. Check whether the `next-auth` supports Next 13 and implement it accordingly

Hope this helps!

Comment: Reverting to using pages directory solved my issues thank you :D