# GET http://localhost:3000/auth/signin 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to navigate to signin.js by using this path http://localhost:3000/auth/signin

Here is my [...nextauth].js code:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Provider from "next-auth/providers/google"


export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
})
```

[Here's my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdhlG.png)

And this the signin.js:

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function signin() {
  return (
    <div>signin</div>
  )
}
```

But i get this error when i try to navigate to this http://localhost:3000/auth/signin path:

[404: This page could not be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r50mV.png)

Answer (score -2):

Please refer my answer on the question  [[next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76789449/next-auth-usesession-must-be-wrapped-in-a-sessionprovider/76789703#76789703) regarding the `app` directory which is intended for `Server Components`

Comment: If you think that content is duplicated, the correct procedure is to flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Daedalus Please be mindful that not all members can do all the actions in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Flagging posts (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) is a privilege you gain access to at 15 rep.